# How can I put header only in the first page and keep the rest without it? I don't want a cover. With the code below, the header appears on every page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\lhead{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{images/image.eps}}
\rhead{
text\\
text\\
text\\
text}

\title{\vspace{-1cm} \centering TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\headheight}{80pt}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Without a full minimal working example, it's hard to say: we don't even know your document class.

Comment: Oh, sorry . The document class is "article"

Comment: Your example only has one page ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one style for the document and an other one just for the first page :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{empty}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\lhead{COUCOU}
\rhead{
text\\
text\\
text\\
text}

\title{\vspace{-1cm} \centering TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}

\setlength{\headheight}{80pt}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

blabla
\newpage
blabla
\newpage
\newpage
blabla
\newpage
\newpage
blabla
\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But the page numbers just disappear

Comment: @EijiWatanabe And you will have a lot of white space at the top of every page!

Comment: for the space at the top see `geometry` package (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf) ; For the numbers pages, you can use `fancyhdr` package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)  to make you own style.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the header is really part of the title: it is a one-off addition to the first page. For example, you probably don't really want to change `\headheight` for your entire document as you'll just end up with ugly space at the top of all pages after the first.

I would, therefore, not use `fancyhdr` for this, but would customise the title. I like to use `titling` for this, although you could do it directly if you preferred.

I didn't have your image so I've substituted a cauldron (available separately) and I altered the text on the right as a check on the alignment I was creating.

`titling` modifies `\maketitle` in various ways. One of these is that it adds various hooks before, between and after the standard title elements. By default, these are empty. However, by redefining them, material can be added wherever required.

Here, we need only redefine `\maketitlehooka` to add material before the title.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{%
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cauldron}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.85\textwidth}
      \raggedleft
      text\par
      more text\par
      yet more text\par
      the final word
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{minipage}\vskip 2.5ex
  \par
  \hrule
}

\title{TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: cauldron topper]

Don't put spacing and markup in the arguments to things like `\title{}`. The default centres the contents anyway and adjustments to vertical spacing are better made elsewhere. Here, I've used `\vskip` at the end of `\maketitlehooka`. I used `2.5ex`. Simply increase or decrease this value according to preference.

This way, we don't need to change the header height and subsequent pages aren't affected. The default page numbering is not affected, so there is not even any need for `fancyhdr` here unless you want to customise the footer or use a custom header on later pages.